# What is the distribution of quotients in Euclid's Algorithm

Tags: probability, number-theory

What is known about the probability distribution of the $n\text{th}$ quotient for randomly chosen co-prime inputs to Euclid's Algorithm from a uniform distribution on $[1,N]$, provided the algorithm does not terminate before the $n\text{th}$ step?

To ensure that this question is clear, I have chosen an example with $n=10$ and with two inputs to Euclid's algorithm that were uniformly chosen from $[1,N]$ with $N$ set to a billion: `372147013` and `242684471`. The $n\text{th}$ ($10\text{th}$) quotient is `47` in this example:

```
372147013 - 1 * 242684471 = 129462542
242684471 - 1 * 129462542 = 113221929
129462542 - 1 * 113221929 = 16240613
113221929 - 6 * 16240613 = 15778251
16240613 - 1 * 15778251 = 462362
15778251 - 34 * 462362 = 57943
462362 - 7 * 57943 = 56761
57943 - 1 * 56761 = 1182
56761 - 48 * 1182 = 25
1182 - 47 * 25 = 7
25 - 3 * 7 = 4
7 - 1 * 4 = 3
4 - 1 * 3 = 1
```

Comment: There is no uniform distribution on the naturals, though I expect you mean the pairs are drawn from the naturals up to a bound $N$ (and then are you letting $N\to\infty$?) You could also consider the Dirichlet density I suppose.

Comment: I was thinking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution. As for letting N go to infinity, that is the more interesting form of the question.